# when i measure external sdcard storage ,give output in negative figure

Tags: java, android, memory, android-sdcard

i know this way  i measure storage of my sdcard but i got storage byte in **-ve figure**

i don't know how my system give me **-ve figure** of storage

i got wrong figure in my external storage only but my internal storage give me perfect figure

i tested in api level 17

how i get original memory size of sdcard?

i am not apply `Formatter.formatShor....` **Log.d("sdcard", "Total  2:"+ tot0 );** becase it's not work for -ve number.

thanks in advance.

**int tot0 = statFs0.getBlockCount() * block0;**

```
//mysdcard path
                StatFs statFs0 = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
                int block0 = statFs0.getBlockSize();
                int avail0 = statFs0.getAvailableBlocks() * block0;
                int tot0 = statFs0.getBlockCount() * block0;

                Log.d("sdcard", "block size 0 :"+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(DemoActivity.this,block0));
                Log.d("sdcard", "free slot 1:"+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(DemoActivity.this,avail0));
                Log.d("sdcard", "Total  2:"+ tot0 );

                //myinternal sdcard path
                StatFs statFs1 = new StatFs("/storage/sdcard1/");
                int block1 = statFs1.getBlockSize();
                int avail1 = statFs1.getAvailableBlocks() * block1;
                int tot1 = statFs1.getBlockCount() *block1;

                Log.d("sdcard", "block slot 4: "+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(DemoActivity.this,block1));
                Log.d("sdcard", "free slot 5:"+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(DemoActivity.this,avail1));
                Log.d("sdcard", "Total 6:"+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(DemoActivity.this,tot1));
```

**my logcat :**

```
09-16 15:28:44.501: D/sdcard(4148): block size 0 :32KB
09-16 15:28:44.501: D/sdcard(4148): free slot 1:1.4GB
```

**09-16 15:28:44.501: D/sdcard(4148): Total  2:-705691648**

```
09-16 15:28:44.502: D/sdcard(4148): block slot 4: 16KB
09-16 15:28:44.503: D/sdcard(4148): free slot 5:845MB
09-16 15:28:44.504: D/sdcard(4148): Total 6:1.3GB
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your SD card has roughly 8 GB of storage, which is `8589934592` as an integer. This does not fit into an `int` value, so the counter overflows, and wraps around a few times. You need to store the value of `statFs0.getBlockCount() * block0` into a `long`, and also declare `block0` *itself* as a long.

```
StatFs statFs0 = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
                Long block0 = (long) statFs0.getBlockSize();
                Long avail0 = statFs0.getAvailableBlocks() * block0;
                Long tot0 = statFs0.getBlockCount() * block0;
```

Comment: it's free slot 1:1.4GB

Comment: It looks like your tot0 variable counts the whole space, not just the free one.

Comment: it's out of range that's why i got in -ve number

Comment: @PRAKASHUBHADIYA OK, so have you tried my answer in its entirety? Has it worked?